# Put my logo on Paypal page when my sellers sells some product from my website

Tags: php, paypal

I am doing paypal integration in my website in a section called stores where an user can sell his products from my store. And i am storing the paypal accounts of my sellers to pay him directly when customer purchase something from his store in my website. Is it possible to put my logo on the paypal checkout page where the seller email id i'm passing will not be mine(Since each sellers will have their own Paypal Business email id)?

Comment: [Check the Docs](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/cowp_summary-outside)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I think the question is if the OP can insert his own branding onto the checkout page of his customers (site users), who seem to each have a different account. I don't have a clue about Paypal, so I probably can't help. Udhay, I'd try doing some searches for `paypal checkout page branding`.

Comment: Yes exactly Jared. My sellers will have their own Paypal seller accounts. And while doing the payment also, the payment is go directly to my sellers and not to me. The only things is the customer will purchase it through my website.

Comment: The [Express Checkout Button and Logo Image Integration](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf#page=17) looks promising. The terminology they use is a little wonky, but you might be able to control the logo image since it's apparently possible to make it a dynamic part of URL. See the [Dynamic Images section](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf#page=17). Keep in mind this only looks promising to me, I've never used or configured PayPal systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make it using PayPal Express Checkout. No need for upgrading to Pro, and paying a fixed monthly fee.

When setting up the express checkout transaction, you have a parameter that tells PayPal which images to show for branding.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/expresscheckout.html#1144280

The parameter name is called **cpp-header-image** which make sure it's delivered through HTTPS otherwise the browser may ask the user is he/she want to see only the securely delivered content.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "PayPal Payments Pro", which allows you to have many options over a typical PayPal account. From X.com (a great resource for learning about the Paypal API Stack), I was able to pull the following link for you (which explains what you are wanting to do)

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-payments-pro