# Can i change label text on paypal?? i m using paypal standard

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to change paypal label text as marked in the attached image below. is there any way to change paypal label text.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding your Custom Header Logo and label text(Need PayPal Premier accounts)

1)http://www.visser.com.au/blog/adding-your-business-logo-to-paypal-checkout

2)http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/paypal/paypal-08.html

3)[Put my logo on Paypal page when my sellers sells some product from my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044599/put-my-logo-on-paypal-page-when-my-sellers-sells-some-product-from-my-website)

Comment: I dont want to change header on paypal. I want to chnage label text as marked in attachment.

Comment: read this link again http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/paypal/paypal-08.html#header

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to change this text on PayPal's pagement page.  You would have to use a different service such as Website Payments Pro and keep the buyer on your page and display the break down of the items/prices on your site.  Pro would allow you to have full control over the checkout flow.